# Processes is waiting for finish

Tags: c#, process

I have an application where I am starting multiple processes. But it looks like I doesn't catch the exit event before all processes has finished. 
How can I do the same but not wait for all to finish?

Here is my code:

```
foreach (var job in JobList.Where(x => x.Status == "Assigned"))
{
    var worker1 = new Process();

    worker1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
    worker1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    worker1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    worker1.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
    worker1.StartInfo.Arguments = job.BtcFilePath;
    worker1.StartInfo.FileName = job.ExeFilePath;
    worker1.Exited += new EventHandler(Worker1Exited);

    Processors.Add(worker1);

    Processors.Last().Start();
    Processors.Last().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal;

    job.Status = "Progressing";
    job.StartDate = worker1.StartTime;
    _jobRespository.Save(job);

    _state = State.CollectWorkerInformation;
}
```

...

```
void Worker1Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref _readyToDoFinalize);
}
```

BR

Comment: Everything looks ok. Can you post Worker1Exited?

Comment: What happens *after* you started those processes? Do you keep the UI thread busy or do you return to the message loop?

Comment: As long as there are not 3 processes running I start them. and then I wait until there are less than 3 processes and starts again. Or that is waht I want. What I see is that it is waiting until all has finished. And I am pretty sure that is because of the exit event is fireing on the same time.